# How to treat/understand some strange signs in string in Java, like %2B, %5E20?

Tags: java, escaping

I debugged the existing project and got a string variable:

```
"q=%2B%28%28%28keywords_en%3A%28pp%3F+OR+pp%29%29%29%29+%28+name%3A%28pp%3F%29%5E20+number%3A%28pp%3F%29%5E20+creator%3A%28OR%5C%3Art.org.WuoUser%5C%3A11%29%5E2+modifier%3A%28OR%5C%3Art.org.WuoUser%5C%3A11%29%5E2+%29+_val_%3A%22recip%28rord%28modifyTimestamp%29%2C1%2C1000%2C1000%29%22%5E2";
```

I am a little confused what these "%2B, %28, %3A, %5E, %5E20" stand for?
If they're some escape character, how can I get the corresponding human-readable letters?
It would be very appreciated if anyone can give some help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is called ["percent encoding"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) often found as part of URI/URL encoding.

Comment: @pst,TedHopp : Thank you all for your valuable information and help. For ^20 part, our system has a full-text search module build on [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) actually. Formats like ^20 or ^2 are used in dismax request handler to set Solr fields' [relevancy score](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_search_for_.22superman.22_in_both_the_title_and_subject_fields) to get the expected results. Thanks for helping me get a better understanding.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer posted was helpful (even if not entirely complete) remember to "accept it". Or, add your own answer and accept that :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can decode it using:

```
String decodedString = URLDecoder.decode(encodedString, "UTF-8");
```

(or whatever character encoding is appropriate if not UTF-8).

Comment: thank you very much for your quick answer. It works and I got the original words, like "q=+(((keywords_en:(pp? OR pp)))) ( name:(pp?)^20 number:(pp?)^20 creator:(OR\:WuoUser\:11)^2". But another question comes, what the ^20, ^2 stands for in Java? Thanks.

Comment: @VincentJia - I don't know what ^20 or ^2 are. They aren't part of the standard Java regular expression syntax (and in any event, that string doesn't look like a RE). Might it be some sort of search specification syntax? (As an operator in Java, `^` is either bitwise or logical XOR. But that doesn't make sense in that string, either.)

Comment: I was trying to add comment and to thank you all, but I got the prompt saying "only one additional ATuser can be notified". I got the answer about ^20 part, thank you.